# How to Access Theme Colors Through SX in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I access the colors of the theme through using `sx`?
I tried below but it doesn't work.

```
<Card
  sx={{
    border: "2px solid primary.main",
  }}
>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As an alternative, you should be able to do:

```
<Card sx={{border: "2px solid", borderColor: "primary.main"}}>
```

The shorthand "border" doesn't seem to access the theme colors properly. Hope that's helpful.

**Update**: Just wanted to add to this that you could also use a function value to set the border color according to your theme.

```
    <Card sx={{border: "2px solid", borderColor: (theme) => theme.palette.primary.main}}>
```

Comment: For more details on these 2 methods, see [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75524473/422845).

Answer (score 11):

I wanted to go a little more in depth on [Tim's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71259428/422845). First, [here's some documentation on the `sx` property itself](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/), and you should also be familiar with the [theme object](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/default-theme/).

But perhaps a better starting point is understanding that there are **2 ways to access theme colors through the `sx` property**:

1. Implicitly (for theme-mappable CSS properties)
2. Explicitly (using a function callback)

### Implicitly (for Theme-Mappable CSS Properties)

```
<Card
  sx={{
    borderColor: 'primary.main'
  }}
>
```

So how/why exactly does this work? [This page](https://mui.com/system/properties/) documents all the style properties you can use for `sx` (in addition you can use any CSS property) and if/how they are linked with the theme. So first that means not all properties link to the theme. If you look at the Properties reference table, the last column ("Theme mapping") tells you if/how the property is linked to the theme object. Let's take a look at a screen shot from that reference table:

[image: MUI system property reference table]

At the bottom, you can see the `display` property is not linked to the theme object. However, near the top, you can see the `borderColor` property *is* linked to the theme object, and the linking is described as `theme.palette[value]`. That means that the value you give it can be a property of the `theme.palette` object. So now let's take a look at [the default theme object](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/default-theme/) to see what values we can pass:

[image: MUI default theme object]

We can see the `theme.palette` object includes a bunch of properties like `common`, `primary`, `secondary`, etc., and underneath these properties, you get actual color values, such as `main`, which is #1976d2. **So putting it altogether, when we specify a `borderColor` of `primary.main`, that is grabbing the value of `theme.palette.primary.main`**. Technically we could even specify a `theme.palette` property not intended for a border color, like `divider` - that would give a border color of `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)`.

### Explicitly (Using a Function Callback)

You can also [pass a function callback](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/#callback-values), which gives you explicit access to the theme base object, and then you can return any value you want using any property of the theme object. In this way we could, for example, specify all the border properties in one go like this:

```
<Card
  sx={{
    border: (theme) => `2px solid ${theme.palette.primary.main}`,
  }}
>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `useTheme()` hook will help:

```js
export default function App() {
  const theme = useTheme()
  return <Card sx={{ border: `2px solid ${theme.palette.primary.main}` }}>...
}
```